# PHP経由で絵文字をMySQLへ挿入しようとするとエラーになるのですが、PHPのエラーかMySQLのエラーか、エラーメッセージから分かりますか？

Tags: php, mysql

PHP(PDO)経由で絵文字をMySQLへ挿入しようとするとエラーになるのですが、PHP(PDO)のエラーかMySQLのエラーか、エラーメッセージから分かりますか？

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB7\x0D\x0A...' for column 'body' at row 1 in hoge.php on line 42
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB7\x0D\x0A...' for column 'body' at row 1 in hoge.php on line 42
```

環境
MySQL 5.7
PHP 7.2

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[utf8mb4を指定してもmysqlで絵文字が文字化けする](https://teratail.com/questions/154097), [Incorrect string value when trying to pass emoji to the db encoded with utf8mb4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947392/9014308), [PHP/mysql site using utf8mb4 won't retrieve emojis correctly from database, despite utf8mb4 being specified everywhere that I can find to put it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983996/9014308), [Emoji character () is not working with utf8mb4_bin in MySQL version 5.6 \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46642129/9014308)

Comment: 解決しました。MySQLのテーブルの文字コード設定がutf8になっていたことが原因でした…….